# Resize image via canvas html5 not working on iPhone 6 or 7 but works on Android?

Tags: ios, html, canvas, ios7, html5-canvas

On Android Phones & Tablets using Google Chrome, this code will work and resize an image correctly and display it on the screen.  On iPhone, the image refuses to show up at all on the screen.  I'm suspect of toDataURL but not sure where the issue might be.  The Canvas might just not work correctly on iPhone 6 & 7 (which I tested both).

```
$("body").on("change",".pictureinputfile",function(){
                    var cid = $(this).attr('cid');
                    var num = $(this).attr('num');

                    //Equivalent of getElementById
                    var fileInput = $(this)[0];//returns a HTML DOM object by putting the [0] since it's really an associative array.

                    var file = fileInput.files[0]; //there is only '1' file since they are not multiple type.

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        // Create a new image.
                        //var img = new Image();

                        var img = document.createElement('img');

                        img.src = reader.result;
                        img.id = "pictureinputfileimage"+cid+"_"+num; //not used just for unique reference.
                        img.setAttribute("class","pictureinputfileimage pictureinputfileimage"+cid);
                        img.setAttribute("style","width:320px;height:240px;");
                        img.setAttribute("cid",cid);
                        img.setAttribute("num",num);

                        //The resultsDIV will remember the pictures for us once it's placed.
                        //localStorage['picInput'+cid+"_"+num] = reader.result;

                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                        var MAX_WIDTH = 640;
                        var MAX_HEIGHT = 480;
                        var width = img.width;
                        var height = img.height;

                        if (width > height) {
                          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                            width = MAX_WIDTH;
                          }
                        } else {
                          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                          }
                        }

                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;

                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                        var shrinked = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

                        img.src = shrinked;

                        img.onload = function() {
                            //console.log("image loaded");

                            $('.fileDisplayArea'+cid).each(function(index,element){
                                //console.log("set to html");
                                var numOfElement = $(this).attr("num");
                                if(numOfElement==num){
                                    $(this).html(img);
                                }
                            });

                            destroyGraphicalState();

                            //Store HTML as it is now without button classes.
                            localStorage.resultsDiv = $('#results').html();//have to clean up classes on button elements.

                            //Restore buttons and graphics states for current session back to normal.
                            restoreGraphicalState();
                        }
                    } //End reader.onload

                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);//attempts to read the file in question.

                    //
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I found the answer.

https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel

Using this library fixed the issue as well as the weird vertical stretch issue.

```
$("body").on("change",".pictureinputfile",function(){
                    var cid = $(this).attr('cid');
                    var num = $(this).attr('num');

                    //Equivalent of getElementById
                    var fileInput = $(this)[0];//returns a HTML DOM object by putting the [0] since it's really an associative array.

                    var file = fileInput.files[0]; //there is only '1' file since they are not multiple type.

                    var mpImg = new MegaPixImage(file);//loads the image.

                    //define an image to work with.
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.id = "pictureinputfileimage"+cid+"_"+num; //not used just for unique reference.
                    img.setAttribute("class","pictureinputfileimage pictureinputfileimage"+cid);
                    img.setAttribute("style","width:320px;height:240px;");
                    img.setAttribute("cid",cid);
                    img.setAttribute("num",num);

                    mpImg.render(img, { maxWidth: 640, maxHeight: 480, quality: 0.5 });//creates the image correctly.

                    $('.fileDisplayArea'+cid).each(function(index,element){
                        //console.log("set to html");
                        var numOfElement = $(this).attr("num");
                        if(numOfElement==num){
                            $(this).html(img);
                        }
                    });

                    destroyGraphicalState();

                    //Store HTML as it is now without button classes.
                    localStorage.resultsDiv = $('#results').html();//have to clean up classes on button elements.

                    //Restore buttons and graphics states for current session back to normal.
                    restoreGraphicalState();
                });
```